# Trying to find orders that only have line items with a specific style and name

Tags: mysql

What I need to do is find each order that only has lineitems with a specific style and names that include 'Commander' in them.

I have two tables, orders and lineitems. Orders does not reference lineitems, but each lineitem has an order_id attached to it.

```
Orders
|id   | is_presale   |  type  |  status  |
| 1   |   1          |  sale  |  ready   |
| 2   |   1          |  sale  |  ready   |
| 3   |   0          |  sale  |  ready   |
| 4   |   1          |  sale  |  ready   |
```

```
Lineitems
|order_id  |  style  |  name             |
| 1        |  NM     | Commander: 1      |
| 1        |  NM     | Commander: 2      |
| 2        |  EX     | Commander: 2      |
| 2        |  NM     | Commander: 2      |
| 2        |  EX     | Something Else: 3 |
```

Here is my current query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) from orders o, lineitems l
WHERE o.type = 'sale'
AND o.is_presale = 1
AND o.status <> 'canceled'
AND l.order_id = o.id
AND l.style = 'NM'
AND l.name LIKE '%Commander%'
```

Right now, the query I built will return all orders that have lineitems that have the specific style and names but will not exclude orders that have lineitems with other styles and names on them as well.

So if the above is a reference to the rows in the two tables, it would count both order 1 and 2 when all I want is order 1.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What do you need as result? The number of order ids or the order ids?

Comment: number of order ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join the tables because you can count the order ids from the table `lineitems`:

```
select
  count(distinct order_id) counter
from lineitems
group by order_id
having 
  count(distinct style) = 1 and sum(style = 'NM') > 0
  and 
  sum(name not like '%Commander%') = 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/acbwHgJT2eVF1siG23KGnx/0).
Results:

```
| counter |
| ------- |
| 1       |
```

If you want to apply other conditions for the table `orders` then join:

```
select count(*) counter
from orders o inner join (
  select
    order_id
  from lineitems
  group by order_id
  having 
    count(distinct style) = 1 and sum(style = 'NM') > 0
    and 
    sum(name not like '%Commander%') = 0 
) t on t.order_id = o.id
where o.type = 'sale'
and o.is_presale = 1
and o.status <> 'canceled'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/acbwHgJT2eVF1siG23KGnx/1).